# Question about Random Effects, Fixed Effects, Maximum Likelihood Estimation, and the Hausman Test

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, panel-data, model-selection, stata

I am working on my thesis and had initially planned to use panel analysis in Stata with the Hausman test determining whether to estimate using random effect ("RE") or fixed effect ("FE"). However, I am considering several models and have been advised to use the AIC/BIC criterion in model selection.

Unfortunately, Stata does not provide AIC and BIC results for the xtreg , re command, but does for the xtreg, mle command. My understanding is that the maximum likelihood estimation ("MLE") is a variant of random effect estimation. If I am to use AIC/BIC in model selection, would it still be appropriate to use the Hausman test to determine between FE and MLE since MLE is a variant of RE? If not, would it be appropriate to test FE and RE as I have, and then use MLE for the regression if RE is preferred under the Hausman test?

Apologies if this is a simple question -- I've been unable to resolve it on my own and am in well over my current understanding of statistics.

Comment: Welcome to CV! While it does not answer your actual question, you generally shouldn't base the choice of fixed vs random on a model selection process. Fixed and random effects have different interpretations. If you include what your goal is (e.g. inference, or prediction) and what the variable is you aren't sure whether to model as fixed or random, it might be easier to answer your question.